# Finding Definition of an Acronym in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I am working on a sample program in C# with Visual Studios 2013.  I have some logic that will find a all uppercase acronym as shown below :

```
string docStr = "Made at Training And Doctrine (TAD)";
string allUpperRegStr = "\\([A-Z]{2,}\\)";
Match mUpper = Regex.Match(docStr, allUpperRegStr);

If  (mUpper.Success)
{
    string remWS = mUpper.Value.Trim();
}
```

So the above logic finds the (TAD) acronym, what I need is some way to parse the sentence and find a match for the definition of the acronym which is Training And Doctrine.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[A-Z][A-Z]+` can be reduced to `[A-Z]+`, btw.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, `[A-Z]+` matches `A`, but `[A-Z][A-Z]+` doesn't. It can be reduced to `[A-Z]{2,}`, though

Comment: @Blorgbeard not true, but it can be reduced to `[A-Z]{2,}`

Comment: Oops, you're (both) right. My mistake.

Comment: @Crayams - You changed it to the _wrong_ alternative (unless you meant to capture single letter acronyms :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should construct a new regex that will look something like `(T[a-z]+\sA[a-z]+\sD[a-z])`, and that should be able to capture "Training And Doctrine". You might have to consider scenarios where the definition contains punctuation characters or other variations (multiple spaces for example), and maybe adjust the regex string accordingly.

> EDIT: **Full Solution** - EDIT2: **Ignore case** (this was not validated to work *yet*)

```
string docStr = "Made at Training And Doctrine (TAD)";
string allUpperRegStr = "\\([A-Z]{2,}\\)";
Match mUpper = Regex.Match(docStr, allUpperRegStr);

if (mUpper.Success)
{
    string remWS = mUpper.Value.Trim();
    char [] chars = remWS.toCharArray();

    IEnumerable<string> lowerUpper = from l in chars
                                     where l !='(' && l != ')'
                                     select string.Format("[{0}{1}][a-z]+", Char.ToLower(l), Char.ToUpper(l));

    string regex2 = string.Format("({0})", string.Join("\\s", lowerUpper));
    Match mDefinition = Regex.Match(docStr, regex2);

    if (mDefinition.Success)
    {
        string definition = mDefinition.Value.Trim();
    }
}
```

Latest fix included:

1. Fixing target regex string (the last character has to be followed by `[a-z]` as well)
2. Strip '(' & ')' from `lowerUpper`
3. [Working regex sample](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5bTt%5d%5ba-z%5d%2b%5cs%2b%5bAa%5d%5ba-z%5d%2b%5cs%2b%5bDd%5d%5ba-z%5d%2b)&i=Made+at+Training+and+Doctrine+(TAD))

Comment: Don't  you mean docStr.toCharArray?  as in put the sentence into an array? the string remWS is actually the acronym.

Comment: Definitely not. I only want the "TAD" string (that's what you have in `remWS`, right??). Look at the result of the string I'm generating.

Comment: Ok I get ya but what about the sentence

Comment: What do you mean? You wanted a regex to capture the acronym definition.. that should be it...

Comment: I meant where do I pass in the variable docStr which contains the sentence?

Comment: Ok so that partially worked but the problem is that it is capturing "at Training And Doctrine" as the definition.

Comment: Also I do need to capture these situations regardless of Case in the definition.  In other words I need to be able to capture the definition if it was "Training and Doctrine"

Comment: @Crayams the fact that it captured "**at** Training And Doctrine" is surprising. I'd have to run the code to understand why, but unfortunately I won't be able to do so in the next few days. As for the letter case, that can be done by changing `chars` with an array of strings where each original letter in `chars` is represented by `[Aa]` ('A' being a placeholder for actual character)

Comment: Ok this gets me far enough but what do you mean by changing the array can you give an example?

Comment: By the way, the modified solution is suitable for cases where the first letter is either lower or upper case, all other letters must be lower case. If that (again ;-) is not what you wanted, then revert to the previous solution and add an ignore case flag to the regex.

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting an error on that line of "The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments".

Comment: That change didn't find any definition.

Comment: Awesome that did it.  Now quick question if the regex for the acronym changed is there anything on the sentence I'd need to find?

Answer (score -2):

Just use the words directly as your regex, like \Training And Doctrine\
A regex parser will recognize the pattern based on a string.

Comment: That's not what the OP wanted.

Comment: The logic requested is to specifically do this _automatically_, not via hard coding.

Comment: The string of the sentence isn't going to be hard coded like that.  I did that just showing a example of the string that may come in.